# Replacing a word followed by a delimited sequence using Regex

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

This is actually a pretty simple question, as far as I'm aware. I'm using Sublime Text, although this question applies to other contexts.

I've got a sequence of strings, like the following:

```
Test_Interface extends
Test_Interface_Foo_Bar {
Test_FooBar implements
Test_FooBarFoo_Bar_Bar_Foo
```

And I want to replace them with:

```
Test\Interface extends
Test\Interface\Foo\Bar {
Test\FooBar implements
Test\FooBarFoo\Bar\Bar\Foo
```

At present, I've been fiddling with back-referencing, but it's not working.

```
^Test((_[A-Za-z0-9]+)\1*)
```

The basic rule is that I need it to find all strings beginning with `Test`, replace the underscores with a backslash, and then stop at a space.

Comment: You mean you need to match all underscores in the first words (non-whitespace sequences) on each line?

Comment: @stribizhev Well, the strings can be technically anywhere in the line, it's basically looking for a string that begins with Test_ and ends with whitespace (a new line, or a space), and replacing every underscore with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex - `^Test((_[A-Za-z0-9]+)\1*)` - matches `Test` only at the beginning of a line/string, then captures a string consisting of a `_`, then alphanumeric symbols (1 or more due to `+`) that is repeated 0 or more times (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ1nK5/1)). In most cases, that means you would only get 2 groups: `Test` and the first `_STRING` after it. You need to move the underscore out of the capture group at least to be able to replace it afterwards.

I think you need a regex based on successful consecutive matches with `\K` to ignore the beginning of the match:

```
(?:Test|(?!^)\G)[^_]*\K_
```

And replace with `\`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV2gY9/3)

If the `Test` must be a whole word, add a `\b` word boundary:

```
(?:\bTest|(?!^)\G)[^_]*\K_
```

In details:

- `(?:\bTest|(?!^)\G)` - a starting boundary that is either the word `Test` or the end of the previous successful match
- `[^_]*` - 0 or more characters other than `_`
- `\K` - ignore-what-has-been-matched-up-to-this-point operator
- `_` - our underscore.

Comment: your first pattern would match `mkkdgdeTest_Interface extends`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly in the demo, but for some reason Sublime Text is matching just underscores. I'll just take a look to see if I can find out why, unless you have any idea!

EDIT: Jesus Christ that's what it's *meant* to do, my bad :P

Comment: I have also added a couple of words about your regex. I hope now you get the general idea of how matching within boundaries can be done.